# Flowplayer, getting events in javascript from flash object

Tags: flowplayer

I'm using Flowplayer to play video's on my site.  I have the FlowPlayer.js loaded on the page as well, but I'm using the object embed codes instead of the pure js embed.

So I have the following

```
<object id="flowplayer" width="480" height="294" data="http://localhost/oembed/Content/flash/flowplayer-3.2.7.swf"
type="application/x-shockwave-flash" bgcolor="#000000">
<param name="movie" value="http://localhost/oembed/Content/flash/flowplayer-3.2.7.swf" />
<param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
<param value="always" name="allowscriptaccess"/>
<param value="true" name="cachebusting"/>
<param name="flashvars" value='config={"clip":{"url":"http://localhost/video.mp4","autoPlay": true}}' />
</object>
```

Now I want to get the onStart, onFinish, and onPause events, but so far I cannot get them to fire for me.

I have tried every combination of $f(...) I can think of, but nothing is working.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Player events are not supported when using alternate embedding methods.  See the Flowplayer docs:
http://flowplayer.org/demos/installation/alternate/index.html (first paragraph)